# Python how to strip end colons of a string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe consisting a column of strings.

```
intcontn1 = [1,2,3,4]

df = 
                       data1     data2  ...     data5       test
2019-09-26 14:53:00  72.847746   6.134  ...  24.175877  intcontn1
2019-09-26 16:13:00  76.124547   3.426  ...  39.138517  intcontn1
2019-09-26 16:53:00  77.714545   1.984  ...  39.868317  intcontn1

print(df['test'].tolist())
['intcontn1', 'intcontn1', 'intcontn1']
```

This looks fine but I want to print without quotes something like this below

```
print(df['test'].tolist())
[intcontn1,intcontn1,intcontn1]
```

How to get this?

Comment: When you are creating the dataframe, it should display it as a list instead of the name of the variable.If you run the below snippet, you should see the actual list in df

`intcontn1 = [1,2,3,4]`
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[intcontn1,intcontn1,intcontn1],'B':[3,4,5],'C':[4,5,8]})`

Comment: That's right. I tried this but could not work because of the size problem.

Comment: Looking at some of the comments, I think this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what your goal is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to print without the apostrophes (`'`)? If so, you could explicitly convert the list to a string and `replace()` the apostrophes with a blank string:

```py
print(str(df['test'].tolist()).replace("'", ""))
[intcontn1, intcontn1, intcontn1]
```

Comment: Looks like it is working but producing additional colons as `'[intcontn1,intcontn1,intcontn1]'`. Conversion could not take place.

Comment: use `eval()` to convert it to the list you want?

Comment: @bombayquant Yes it is working. I have one more question. How to add a string to each element in the list? for instance how to convert `[intcontn1,intcontn1,intcontn1]` into `[intcontn1[0],intcontn1[0],intcontn1[0]]`

Comment: @Mainland You really shouldn't use `eval()`, especially for this. You should clarify in your question what you're actually trying to do.